# RSS reader uses PHP any work around on a non PHP server?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript

This is called from flash/action script
File name: rssProxy.php
RSS reader uses PHP any work around on a non PHP server?
Script below:

```
<?php
$rss = $_GET['rss'];
// make sure that some page is really being called
if ($rss && $rss != ""){
    // make sure that an http call is being made - otherwise there's access to any file on machine...
    if ((strpos($rss, "http://") === 0) || (strpos($rss, "https://") === 0)){
        readfile($rss);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: What was the reasoning behind the edit?

Comment: What scripting your server does have?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the action script links to `http://www.example.org/rssProxy.php?rss=path/file.xml` you should get the same result by just linking to `http://www.example.org/path/file.xml` as long as the path directory is public accessable.

Answer (score 0):

You can [parse the RSS directly in flash](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/01/22/parsing-rss-20-feeds-in-actionscript-3/).